# permutations of matrix oriented lements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

folks,

lets assume i have 16 different objects. that gives me 16! arrangements.
now i place them in a 4 x 4 matrix - which still gives me 16! arrangements.
now lets restrict the movements to vectors, that is, i can permute the 4 rows (which gives me 4!
different arrangements) or the 4 columns, which gives me another 4! arrangements - or both, which
gives me 4! * 4! different arrangements. Let's call this an 'orbit' - you cycle through all possible vector permutations and are back at step1.

This way, i *cannot* reach all of the 16! possible arrangements. Lets ignore matrix-rotation for now. Reflection along horzontal and vertical axis is included in the row/column permutations.

I am aware of some kind of 'normalization', that is a way to find one specifc permutation, which allows me to check, if two random arrangements belong to the same orbit.

1.) how do i need to swap pairs of single elements (not vectors) to reach the other orbits?
Of course, *any* swap of two elements will move me into another orbit - how can i avoid previously visited orbits? if i swap element 3 and 4 of row 1, i am in another orbit. when i swap 3/4 in row 2 -> i am in another orbit. When i swap 3/4 in row 3 -> yet another orbit. but when i swap 3/4 in row 4, i am back to the initial orbit, with just column 3 and 4 swapped. Not all pair-swaps are the way forward!

The 'real' problem is a little more sophisticated: it is known, that a vector with elements (2,5,1,11 - row or column doesnt matter) (and some other vectors) is *never* part of any solution.
That is, all orbits which contain (1,2,5,11) are to be avoided. i guess, its not possible to know all invalid vectors in advance, but it is cheap to check them when they occur - but they must be avoided, so they dont show up again and again.

2.) how is this thing called? what do i need to google to find more information about this?

any hints or clues, where to start searching?

thanks from sunny Hamburg

dvh